# Is there a way to force gzip not to overwrite files on conflict?

Tags: command-line, gzip

I'm writing a script in which I'm gzipping files.

There's a possibility that I might zip a file, create a file of the same name, and try to gzip this as well, e.g.

```
$ ls -l archive/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 xyzzy xyzzy  0 Apr 16 11:29 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 xyzzy xyzzy 24 Apr 16 11:29 foo.gz

$ gzip archive/foo
gzip: archive/foo.gz already exists; do you wish to overwrite (y or n)? n   
    not overwritten
```

By using `gzip --force`, I can force gzip to overwrite `foo.gz`, but in this case, I think that there's a good chance that I might lose data if I overwrite `foo.gz`. There doesn't seem to be a command line switch to force gzip to leave `.gz` files alone... a non-interactive version of pressing 'n' at the prompt.

I tried `gzip --noforce` and `gzip --no-force`, hoping that these might follow the GNU options standard, but neither of these worked.

Is there a straight forward work-around for this?

Edit:

It turns out that this is one of the times that it pays to read the info page rather than the man page.

From the info page:

```
`--force'
`-f'
     Force compression or decompression even if the file has multiple
     links or the corresponding file already exists, or if the
     compressed data is read from or written to a terminal.  If the
     input data is not in a format recognized by `gzip', and if the
     option `--stdout' is also given, copy the input data without
     change to the standard output: let `zcat' behave as `cat'.  If
     `-f' is not given, and when not running in the background, `gzip'
     prompts to verify whether an existing file should be overwritten.
```

The man page was missing the text *and when not running in the background*

When running in the background, gzip will not prompt, and will not overwrite unless the `-f` option is invoked.

Comment: I'm not sure how gzip checks for being backgrounded, but adding '&' in bash on the system I'm working on doesn't do it.  Being on the other side of a pipe seems to work, though, so instead of:

    `find ./ ! -name "*gz" -exec gzip {} \; &`

this works:

    `find ./ ! -name "*gz" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -t gzip` 

gzip reports:

    `gzip: ./2012-July.txt.gz already exists; not overwritten`

Comment: @BillMcGonigle Your comment should be THE answer!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It has dawned on me that the best way to avoid the undesired effect is to *not* ask the program to perform the undesired effect. That is, simply don't tell it to compress a file if the file is already present in compressed form.

e.g:

```
if [ ! -f "$file.gz" ]; then 
    gzip "$file"; 
else 
    echo "skipping $file"
fi
```

or shorter (run `true` if there is a file.gz, compress file otherwise)

```
[ -f "$file.gz" ] && echo "skipping $file" || gzip "$file"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is being run as a system command inside a perl script (long story about why we're not using something like IO::Compress::Gzip, trust me, I've thought about it). The compression command itself is stored in a configuration file. Your latter command looks close to what I need, but I think that I've found something that will fit my needs just a little bit better. I'm going to accept your answer, because it's a better general solution than mine, but see below for what I'm actually going to use.

Comment: You can poke a file in Perl...

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by `poke a file`.

Comment: Lack of association/image use in everyday communications in American English surprises me every time :) Let me try and explain. Conjure up an image of a child poking a dead crow with a stick to see if it's alive or what not. *Poking* is used to *probe for attributes* here. Similarly, *poking a file* would mean to check something about it, such as *if* it is at all present. At any rate, I *feel* the act of poking should at the very least mean *"attain contact with an exterior object"*, and *that* is enough to say *"get some information about a file"* with an image, instead of spelling it out.

Comment: "poke" is often hacker slang for setting a memory location.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEEK_and_POKE#Generic_usage_of_.22POKE.22

Comment: I use good old `find -name "*.log" -exec -v {} \;`

Answer (score 20):

The closest thing that I could find to a single command is the following:

```
yes n | gzip archive/foo
```

The `yes` command prints `y` followed by a linefeed to stdout until it receives a signal. If it has an argument, it will print that instead of `y`. In this case, it prints `n` until gzip exits, thus closing the pipe.

This is the equivalent of entering `n` repeatedly on the keyboard; this will automatically answer the question `gzip: archive/foo.gz already exists; do you wish to overwrite (y or n)?`

I general, I think that it's better not to try to compress the files if the corresponding gzipped file exists; my solution is noisier, but it fits my particular needs for a drop-in replacement for the `gzip` command, sitting in a configuration file.

Comment: another annoyance with this is that `gzip` exits `2`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
gzip -d -r ./folder && gzip -r ./folder
```

Comment: Any sort of explantation of why this command helps would be welcome.